# Ryzen voltage on Ubuntu

Tags: cpu, temperature, amd-processor, amd-ryzen, lm-sensors

I started machine on Ubuntu with Ryzen 7 3800x and want to check CPU temp and voltage.
I already installed the newest kernel: `Linux 5.12.0-051200rc6-generic`
I've added: `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` rebooted and did `sensors-detect`

My sensors:

```
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           1.80 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in1:           1.33 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in2:           1.21 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
+3.3V:         1.68 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in4:           1.34 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in5:           1.22 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in6:           2.78 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)  ALARM
3VSB:          1.68 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
Vbat:          1.60 V  
fan1:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +27.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +32.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp3:        +33.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
intrusion0:  ALARM

radeon-pci-0700
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +58.0°C  

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +40.9°C  
Tdie:         +40.9°C  
Tccd1:        +34.8°C  

nvme-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +36.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +85.8°C)
                       (crit = +86.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +36.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +36.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
```

What is my CPU temperature? Is it here?
Which one is my CPU voltage? Is it here at all? :)

Answer (score 0):

`Tctl` (T control) is the CPU Temperature.